# Ошибка при создании таблицы БД в 1С Битрикс

Tags: база-данных, битрикс

После запуска тестирование системы на ошибки в пункте Структура базы данных вылезла ошибка "Ошибочный ответ сервера. Не удалось завершить тестирование"
Вот код ошибки:

```
MySQL Query Error: 
create table `site_checker_b_forum_file` ( 
ID int(18) not null auto_increment,
FORUM_ID int(18) null REFERENCES B_FORUM(ID),
TOPIC_ID int(20) null,
MESSAGE_ID int(20) null,
FILE_ID int(18) not null REFERENCES B_FILE(ID), 
USER_ID int(18) null, 
TIMESTAMP_X timestamp not null, 
HITS int(18) null, primary key (ID), 
index IX_FORUM_FILE_FILE(FILE_ID), 
index IX_FORUM_FILE_FORUM(FORUM_ID), 
index IX_FORUM_FILE_TOPIC(TOPIC_ID), 
index IX_FORUM_FILE_MESSAGE(MESSAGE_ID) 
)
[[1005] Can't cre ate table `bitrix`.`site_checker_b_forum_file` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать чтобы исправить.
Полный код ошибки:

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR                                                                                                                                                        
------------------------  
Error in foreign key constraint of table `bitrix`.`site_checker_b_forum_file`:                                                               
Create  table `bitrix`.`site_checker_b_forum_file` with foreign key (FORUM_ID) constraint failed. Referenced table `bitrix`.`B_FORUM` not found in the data dictionary.---------
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Проблема возникает из-за того, что в настройках MySQL установлено регистрозависимое имя таблиц:

```
lower_case_table_names=0
```

Решений два:

1. установить в /etc/my.cnf переменную lower_case_table_names=1. Предварительно стоит убедиться, что во всех базах данных, развёрнутых на сервере MySQL нет таблиц, созданных в разных регистрах. В противном случае могут возникнуть проблемы.
2. изменить SQL-файл /bitrix/modules/forum/install/mysql/install.sql, который используется для создания таблиц и при Проверки системы (проверка структуры базы данных) и заменить в нём REFERENCES B_FORUM(ID) и REFERENCES B_FILE(ID) на REFERENCES b_forum(ID) и  REFERENCES b_file(ID) соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно структура БД была изменена какими-нибудь установками модулей, и что-то пошло не так.
Попробуйте вручную (например, через [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org)) исправить структуру БД, как просит ошибка. Похоже сейчас нет нужной таблицы B_FORUM.
Либо, если есть возможность, откатитесь через бекап на тот момент, когда такой проблемы небыло.

Comment: Проблема в том что таблица B_FORUM существует и там есть даже запись

Answer (score 0):

Да, вся проблема была в регистре имен таблиц.
Но, лучше не менять регистр на нижний, а лучше lower_case_table_names=1.
Т.к. может обновиться и затереться и не известно какой гений и где еще напишет имена таблиц в разных регистрах.